# NODEJS node-mysql cannot pass query results in nested queries

Tags: mysql, json, node.js, angularjs, callback

I am using node, angular and mysql, the node routes would return a json that would be processed by angular, the json is returned by first querying the mysql DB using the node-mysql module,
In the below code I am unable to set the value of `CreatedID`, but the value gets logged properly in terminal. I was facing the same issue in the 1st query but then sorted it in the below code, now unable to access the nested query results.

```
           var mysql =  require('node-mysql/node_modules/mysql');

 var connection =  mysql.createConnection({
    host : 'localhost',
    user : "root",
    password: "",
    database:'designtaskmanager'
  });
 connection.connect();
var allDbCalls = function() {
   var sendData = {};
   var rowData = {};
   var temp={};
   var _this = this;
   this.sendTask = function(callback) {
     module.exports.taskData =  rowData;
     callback['success']();
  };



  this.getTask = function(callback) {
    var strQuery = "select * from  task"; 
    connection.query( strQuery, function(err, rows){
      if(err) 
      {
        callback['failure']();
        throw err;
      }
      else
      {
        //rowData = rows;
        var tasks=[];

        for (var i in rows) 
        {
            var Title = rows[i].task_title;
            var TaskDescription=rows[i].task_description;
            var TaskCategory=rows[i].task_category;
            var TaskID=rows[i].task_id;
            var TaskStatus=rows[i].task_status;
            var TaskStatusMessage
            var CreatedBy;
            var TaskCreationDate=rows[i].task_creation_date;
            var _MS_PER_DAY = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;



            var currentdate = new Date(); 

            var ddd=dateDiffInDays(TaskCreationDate,currentdate);

            function dateDiffInDays(a, b) {
              // Discard the time and time-zone information.
              var utc1 = Date.UTC(a.getFullYear(), a.getMonth(), a.getDate());
              var utc2 = Date.UTC(b.getFullYear(), b.getMonth(), b.getDate());

              return Math.floor((utc2 - utc1) / _MS_PER_DAY);
            }

            if(TaskStatus==0)
            {
              TaskStatus="label-info";
              TaskStatusMessage="Ongoing since";

            }
            else if(TaskStatus==1)
            {
              TaskStatus="label-default";
              TaskStatusMessage="Paused since"

            } 
            else if(TaskStatus==2)
            {
              TaskStatus="label-success";
              TaskStatusMessage="Completed in"

            }

            //USER DETAILS QUERY
            var crid=rows[i].task_created_by;
            var creatorQuery = "select user_email from  users where user_id like ?";

            connection.query( creatorQuery,[crid], function(err, createdbyrows){
              if(err) 
              {
                callback['failure']();
                throw err;
              }
              else
              {
                for(var j=0; j< createdbyrows.length;j++)
                {
                  CreatedBy=createdbyrows[0].user_email;
                  console.log(j);


                }

                  console.log(CreatedBy);

              }
          });


            var taskItem={"TaskID":TaskID,"TaskTitle":Title,"TaskDescription":TaskDescription,"TaskCategory":TaskCategory,"CreatedBy":CreatedBy,"TaskStatus":TaskStatus,"TaskStatusMessage":TaskStatusMessage,"DifferenceInDays":ddd};

          tasks.push(taskItem);

        }

          rowData=tasks;
           _this.sendTask(callback);   
      }
    });
  }

}
module.exports = function () {
  var instance = new allDbCalls();
  return instance;
};
```

Comment: You also may want to think about using JOINS.  Using loops to look up more data is going to be less efficient in many cases.  For example, your query would be ```SELECT t.*, e.user_email FROM tasks t JOIN users u ON (u.user_id = t.task_created_by)```.  That will give you everything from the tasks table, plus the email of the user_id that created each task.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that you're seeing it on the console but not in the callback is due to a misunderstanding of asynchronous programming.  When you:

```
for(var i in rows) {}
```

You are actually queuing up all of those queries at the same time, then, immediately after you try to set rowData to an empty array:

```
rowData=tasks; // remember, none of the queries have finished yet
_this.sendTask(callback);
```

So you pretty much call your callback when tasks is still an empty array.  Remember, you can't call your final callback until ALL of your nested queries have finished!

To accomplish this, you may want to look at the async library: https://github.com/caolan/async#eachSeries

This will help you accomplish what you really want.

```
var async = require("async");
async.eachSeries(rows, function(row, cb) {
   // Do each query here
   // then call cb() when done, which tells the async library 
   // to "go to the next item in the array"
}, function(err) {
   // This will get called when all of the single queries are finished
   // Check err, then call your callback
   _this.sendTask(callback);   
});
```

Comment: can you point me to a basic example for mysql that returns a json to a route

Comment: You may want to check out an ORM like http://sequelizejs.com/articles/express that will do much of this your you (work with Express, turn rows into objects, etc).